# What is a community wiki?

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

I am seeing this term coming up at times. And I had been asked if I wish to do a wiki once. Seems that I should start to get to know something about the term. Hope that someone could help ...

Answer (score 6):

[Here is some info on community wikis](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts).

Here at EL&U, a question will/should be made into a community wiki when there are many right answers; for example, ["what words are commonly mispronounced by literate people who read them before they heard them?"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1431/what-words-are-commonly-mispronounced-by-literate-people-who-read-them-before-the).

Answer (score 4):

We have provided some additional guidance at the blog:

http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/the-future-of-community-wiki/

TL;DR version

> Most of the time, you should be asking yourself “How can I improve this post so that community wiki isn’t needed?” Community wiki is like a cheese knife: it is a specialized tool to be used sparingly, and only in very specific circumstances.